# Redirect all but one sub domain to https?

Tags: linux, redirect, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857334/nginx-redirect-everything-from-http-to-https-except-one-url-pattern) post is very close to what I am looking for. But what I am looking for is

```
letsencrypt.example.com   should always be http
          *.example.com   should always be https
```

Using the solution from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx) post I can rewrite all http to https by

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.example.com;
  rewrite     ^   https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

and then onwards do

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ...
```

**Question**

But how can I make sure that `letsencrypt.example.com` remains at http port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an explicit server for `letsencrypt.example.com` and then use a catch-all server for the redirection.

Your port 80 server blocks would look Like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name letsencrypt.example.com;
    ...
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

See [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.