# Nginx: Redirect all to https except one laravel url = too many redirects

Tags: laravel, nginx

So I finally found the way to redirect all the traffic from www to non www and from http to https, but I have an exception, a laravel web.php route called tpv that I don't want to be redirected. If the user go to https then it's ok, but if they decide http, then its ok as well without redirection

So I integrated it in the following code, and I changed the code with different ideas, but all end up with "too many redirects"

What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
# Redirect every request to HTTPS...
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /home/forge/example.com/public;
location /tpv {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
server_name .example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

# Redirect SSL to primary domain SSL...
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

server_name www.example.com;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com;
root /home/forge/example.com/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: you've having an infinite redirect. it can be a problem with your routing.

Comment: This might help: 
[nginx: redirect everything from http to https except one url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857334/nginx-redirect-everything-from-http-to-https-except-one-url-pattern/27866255#27866255)

Comment: @Wreigh it has to be something in the code I attached, as the rute just points to a laravel controller to record a mysql query

Comment: @ColeTierney I've followed that post, and applied but I still get the loop. I've tried a lot of solutions, but I might be missing something

Comment: Is this your whole configuration? I see only one open ended server stanza and the listen and server_name directives suggest there should be two.